# PHP/Html - Issue with integer comparison and redirection

Tags: php, html

I've been having an issue with comparing two integers, both coming from different php sections on the same page.

The first integer is being generated using the rand() function as follows:

```
<?php
    $rand_otp = rand(100000, 999999);
    (.. code to email the generated integer ..)
?>
```

I then have a form that requests a number. The **$rand_otp** is sent to an email and the user is prompted to input the integer.

The form:

```
<div align="middle">
    <form action="" method="POST" align="middle">
        <p>Please enter the generated One-Time Pin</p>
        <input type="number" name="otp" placeholder="OTP" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="login" value="run">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</div>
```

The php after the form:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
     $OTP = $_POST['otp'];

    if ($OTP == $rand_otp) {
       $redirect_to = "admin.html";
       echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "'.$redirect_to.'" </script>';
    } else {
       $redirect_to = "login.php";
       echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "'.$redirect_to.'" </script>';
    }
}
```

Both parts of the php sections are on the same page as well.

The problem I am currently having is that once the user inputs the number given to them, it simply redirects them back to the **login.php** page and not the **admin.html** page, no matter wether or not the number is correct.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use `header('Location: ' . $redirect_to); http_response_code(302);`instead of echoing a javascript. Your solution is ugly as hell.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I figured it was a pretty ugly, albeit functioning solution, but this definitely works. Could you explain what the http_response_code(302) does?

Comment: After every http request, the webserver sends a http status code back to the client (most times browser). The default status code is 200, wich means that the request was successfull. There are many status codes. You can find a list e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

302 indicates a temporary redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store generated `$rand_otp` in `$_SESSION['otp']` then compare `$_POST['otp']` with `$_SESSION['otp']`

Comment: Awesome! This seems to have worked perfectly. Thank you for the quick and great response.